# Proxy help on Kali Linux

Tags: proxy, anonymity, kali-linux

I've recently gotten into using tor and I understand that tor only handles tcp. What I was hoping was to route all of my network traffic from my local machine through what I, at the time, thought of as tor's proxy then I did my research and learned that it wasn't a thing. So my next question was I was wondering if there was a reliable/safe proxy that worked as well as tor does but can handle all of my network protocols like ssh ftp telnet etc that anyone would recommend? Money's kind of tight for now so I was looking to do some security tests on my own personal things like my email. I tried doing research and there's so many free proxies out there but I don't want to just deal with tcp protocol or using a browser. Anything free, reliable, and anonymous? In the sense that it gives me an ip address that doesn't show where/who I am.

I'm going into my knowledge hunt with the mentality that the best defense is a good offense. If I have a good understanding of how attackers compromise things, I can know how to patch things up and throw in a few roadblocks

Comment: Unfortunately, product recommendations are off-topic on this site.

Comment: So you are basically looking for a free Anonymity VPN service?

Comment: @SimplyG. That would work